# Do I need to regression test existing methods on a Web service if new methods are added

Tags: web-services, soap, integration-testing

We have a SOAP web service that is in production and contains a large number of methods. As part of a project we are adding new methods to that web service, note we are not amending the existing methods.

What I am trying to determine is whether I need to regression test the existing methods to test if they have been impacted by adding new methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you change your webservice the only proper way to make sure none of the changes have impacted existing operations is a regression test.

If you use a testing tool like SOAPUI you can automate this for every build you make. (Regression) testing should be a standard step after any new build to ensure software quality.